# MySQL STR_TO_DATE failing on times before 1970

Tags: mysql

I receive dates from files in various formats like m/d/Y or m-d-Y or Y-m-d.  I need to normalize all of these to Y-m-d to store in a VARCHAR column in my 8.0+ MySQL instance, eventually these dates will be stored in a DATETIME column so that's why I want them in the correct format before I dump them into that other table.

I am running the following query to clean the data:

```
UPDATE users
        SET birthday =
            CASE
                WHEN STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y') > NOW() THEN DATE_SUB(str_to_date(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y'), INTERVAL 100 YEAR)
                WHEN STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y') < NOW() THEN STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y')
                WHEN STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m-%d-%Y') > NOW() THEN DATE_SUB(str_to_date(birthday, '%m-%d-%Y'), INTERVAL 100 YEAR)
                WHEN STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m-%d-%Y') < NOW() THEN STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m-%d-%Y')
                WHEN STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%Y-%m-%d') > NOW() THEN DATE_SUB(str_to_date(birthday, '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 100 YEAR)
                WHEN STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%Y-%m-%d') < NOW() THEN STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%Y-%m-%d')
            END
```

This was working perfectly fine in MySQL 5.7 but something changed when I migrated to 8.0+, older dates will throw the error: `Incorrect datetime value: '1955-01-01' for function str_to_date` .  I have googled like crazy and can't figure out what changed between 5.7 and 8.0 to cause this behavior or how to fix it.

I've tried checking the value of the STR_TO_DATE function for NULL but that doesnt work as I would expect either.  I've tried setting the sql_mode to include ALLOW_INVALID_DATES but no dice.  Any tips greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why has your database got dates stored as strings

Comment: [As per the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), the second argument to `STR_TO_DATE` is a string, so at the very least change all those `STR_TO_DATE(birthday, %m/%d/%Y)` etc. to `STR_TO_DATE(birthday, "%m/%d/%Y")` etc.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans fixed that, they were being passed as strings but I pasted it incorrectly into here.

Comment: @RiggsFolly because this is a pre-processing table that I use to clean up data before inserting it into the actual data table with the DATETIME column

Comment: Seems to work just fine! [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eck9SxMf6wYHDq28EGyocW/1)

Comment: This also seems to run [Another fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eck9SxMf6wYHDq28EGyocW/6)

Comment: I agree that this query works fine in a select, I tried that myself too.  But it doesn't work in an update.  It might be some sort of server config value that's changed, I'm not sure.

Comment: I've added a small picture at the bottom of my post to show that the query gives the error in my DB.  I just dont know what other variables I'm not seeing here.

Comment: The problem is UPDATE and INSERT queries turn warnings into errors. So when `STR_TO_DATE()` can't match the pattern, it issues a warning in SELECT, but causes `UPDATE` to fail. You need to check whether `birthday` is valid for a particular pattern before calling `STR_TO_DATE()` with that pattern.

Comment: You might be able to use `UPDATE IGNORE` to make it ignore these errors.

Comment: @Barmar The behaviour seems very inconsistent but `UPDATE IGNORE` allows me to do what I want to do for now, thanks!  I still dont quite understand the root cause of what started breaking this query when migrating from 5.7 to 8.0, all the server vars seem the same.

Comment: The default SQL_MODE probably changed.